# Pyomo: Limit number of iterations

Tags: python, pyomo

I have a Pyomo model that eventually gets solved like so:

```
solver  = SolverFactory('ipopt')
results = solver.solve(model,tee=False)
```

The model current runs for 3000 iterations before giving up.

In my mind, there must be a way to use one of these two lines to limit the number of iterations. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work?

```
solver  = SolverFactory('ipopt')
solver.options['max_iter'] = 10
results = solver.solve(model,tee=False)
```

Comment: That does, thanks! How did you know this? I didn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Great! In the [Online Documentation (18.12 Sending options to the solver)](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoOnlineDocs.html#_sending_options_to_the_solver) they show how they send options to the solver.

Comment: And in the [Ipopt documentation](https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node40.html#app.options_ref) there is the max_iter option mentioned. Apparently, you can also see the options by running `ipopt --print-options`.

Comment: I should add that Pyomo sends options to ipopt via the command line. These options are processed by ASL and they can be seen by typing "ipopt -=". The output from "--print options" documents the full set of ipopt options, and they can only be set through an options file, the name of which you can provide via a command-line option.