# Pyomo/CBC: Limit the number of iterations

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming, coin-or-cbc

I'm solving a Pyomo model with `cbc` using:

```
solver  = SolverFactory('cbc')
results = solver.solve(model, tee=False)
```

Is it possible to let cbc/pyomo terminate early after a specific number of iterations?

Tried setting the `max_iter` option as suggested in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41010431/3023615), but it does not seem to work when using `cbc` as the solver.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the other answer mentioned, I usually have to dig for the right keywords between different solvers....

If your installation of `cbc` is "standard" and you can (and should be able to) access it from the command line, just type "cbc" in the command line and then the question mark to see options/commands and then that command for more info.

I typically don't find need to limit iterations, which I think is a bit arbitrary....  If the model is long, I will usually put both a time limit on it *and* a relative gap limit, which I find more useful, which gets to something like this:

```
solver.options = { 'sec': <sec>,  'threads':6, 'ratio': 0.02}
```

Example from terminal:

```
~ % cbc
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.8 
Build Date: Jul 21 2022 

CoinSolver takes input from arguments ( - switches to stdin)
Enter ? for list of commands or help
Coin:?
In argument list keywords have leading - , -stdin or just - switches to stdin
One command per line (and no -)
abcd? gives list of possibilities, if only one + explanation
abcd?? adds explanation, if only one fuller help
abcd without value (where expected) gives current value
abcd value sets value
Commands are:
Double parameters:
 dualB(ound) dualT(olerance) primalT(olerance) primalW(eight) psi
 zeroT(olerance)
Branch and Cut double parameters:
 allow(ableGap) cuto(ff) inc(rement) integerT(olerance) preT(olerance)
 pumpC(utoff) ratio(Gap) sec(onds)
Integer parameters:
 force(Solution) idiot(Crash) maxF(actor) maxIt(erations) output(Format)
 randomS(eed) slog(Level) sprint(Crash)
Branch and Cut integer parameters:
 cutD(epth) cutL(ength) depth(MiniBab) hot(StartMaxIts) log(Level) maxN(odes)
 maxSaved(Solutions) maxSo(lutions) passC(uts) passF(easibilityPump)
 passT(reeCuts) pumpT(une) randomC(bcSeed) slow(cutpasses) strat(egy)
 strong(Branching) trust(PseudoCosts)
Keyword parameters:
 allC(ommands) chol(esky) crash cross(over) direction error(sAllowed)
 fact(orization) keepN(ames) mess(ages) perturb(ation) presolve
 printi(ngOptions) scal(ing) timeM(ode)
Branch and Cut keyword parameters:
 clique(Cuts) combine(Solutions) combine2(Solutions) constraint(fromCutoff)
 cost(Strategy) cplex(Use) cuts(OnOff) Dins DivingS(ome) DivingC(oefficient)
 DivingF(ractional) DivingG(uided) DivingL(ineSearch) DivingP(seudoCost)
 DivingV(ectorLength) dw(Heuristic) feas(ibilityPump) flow(CoverCuts) GMI(Cuts)
 gomory(Cuts) greedy(Heuristic) heur(isticsOnOff) knapsack(Cuts) lagomory(Cuts)
 latwomir(Cuts) lift(AndProjectCuts) local(TreeSearch)
 mixed(IntegerRoundingCuts) node(Strategy) PrepN(ames) pivotAndC(omplement)
 pivotAndF(ix) preprocess probing(Cuts) proximity(Search) randomi(zedRounding)
 reduce(AndSplitCuts) reduce2(AndSplitCuts) residual(CapacityCuts) Rens Rins
 round(ingHeuristic) sosO(ptions) sosP(rioritize) two(MirCuts)
 Vnd(VariableNeighborhoodSearch) zero(HalfCuts)
Actions or string parameters:
 allS(lack) barr(ier) basisI(n) basisO(ut) directory dualS(implex)
 either(Simplex) end exit export gsolu(tion) guess help import initialS(olve)
 max(imize) min(imize) para(metrics) primalS(implex) printM(ask) quit
 restoreS(olution) saveS(olution) solu(tion) stat(istics) stop
Branch and Cut actions:
 branch(AndCut) doH(euristic) mips(tart) nextB(estSolution) prio(rityIn) solv(e)
Coin:maxIT?
maxIt(erations) : Maximum number of iterations before stopping
Coin:
```

Answer (score 1):

Option names can vary from solver to solver so double check the valid solver options for cbc to find the option for specifying the max number of iterations and then set it as described in the SO post you linked.