# Sonnet/CBC: Limit the number of iterations

Tags: .net, coin-or-cbc

I use the [Sonnet wrapper](https://github.com/coin-or/Sonnet) to solve MIPs in .Net with the CBC solver from COIN-OR (from the [NuGet Package CoinCBC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoinCbc)). My sample model works (see code below), but I am stuck on how to pass additional options to the solver. **I need to limit the number of iterations.** How can I do this?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73464910/342594), but it is related to Pyomo and Sonnet doesn't have the options property.

Any help highly appreciated.

Here is the test code I use (model taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/mip_example?hl=de#c_1)):

```
Sonnet.Model model = new Sonnet.Model("GoogleExample");

Variable x = new Variable(VariableType.Integer);
Variable y = new Variable(VariableType.Integer);

model.Add(x + 7 * y <= 17.5);
model.Add(0 <= x <= 3.5);
model.Add(0 <= y);
model.Objective = new Expression(x + 10 * y);


Solver solver = new Solver(model);

solver.Maximise();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the question was only relevant for a small audience I asked in another forum as well and I got an answer, which I want to share here for whomever it may be helpful.

You can limit the execution time in two ways. First one is by setting a solver parameter:

```
Solver solver = ….
OsiCbcSolverInterface osiCbc = solver.OsiSolver as OsiCbcSolverInterface;
osiCbc.AddCbcSolverArgs("-sec", "5");
```

Second one is to manipulate the model itself:

```
osiCbc.getModelPtr().setMaximumSeconds(5.0);
```

Credits go out to [jhmgoossens](https://github.com/coin-or/Sonnet/discussions/39#discussioncomment-8645779).

Thanks.
Sascha